# Disappearing divs in Opera, when internal link clicked

Tags: css

I have problem with a disappearing div in Opera.
When you click on a link, the header disappears...
Please help.

```
 <style type="text/css">

  body {
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#top { 
    position:fixed;   
    height: 60px; 
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: #ccc;
    width:100%; 
    z-index:100;
    }

#content {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:0;
    padding-top:70px;   
}

 h1 {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

 </style>
```

[problem example](http://jsfiddle.net/KNdcL/show)

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's hard to tell what you want exactly.

Comment: Please you see example link. http://jsfiddle.net/KNdcL/show Then you clicking on text links on sample pages. Grey div disappear...

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome (Win)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the 'fixed' position for #top.

Try:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
```